# OpenLayers trigger map click on specific coordinates

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I am working with web map application *Lizmap* which unfortunately is working with OpenLayers 2.

I want to trigger map click programically on specific position:

```
let event = new Event("click");
event.xy = {x: 400, y: 400};      // sample values
map.events.triggerEvent("click", event);    // map - OpenLayers map object
```

Everything works ok until I move map. After map move this doesn't work. I cannot trigger map click  that way anymore and I have no idea why. I tried to debug OpenLayers to find out what's going on but I'm really stuck at this point.

I found this problem, but its not completed:

[How to trigger a map click event?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37675/how-to-trigger-a-map-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for a different event triggering method [here](https://aviationweather.gov/lib/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html).

Comment: Link-only answers are often deleted, because links fail over time. Please Edit your answer to contain the meat of the linked content.

Comment: I tried different methods, but didn't find anything helpful.